# cq5. How to show list publishers for author? version 5.5

Tags: java, aem

I am novice in CQ5.

I have installed publisher and author instances.

How can I check that my author connects with my publisher?

Comment: You should have a look at the [docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/replication.html) first. Configuring your Replication agents and then testing the connection should do. In case this isn't what you are looking for, kindly add additional info to the question describing your problem.

Comment: I don't have a problem - I am sure that somewhere exist place there I can see relation  between author and publishers.

Comment: @ rakhi4110 I have the configuration and I need to check pubilshers for author.

Comment: /etc/replication/agents.author.html would give you the list of agents and to which server they are configured and what is the current state of the agents

Comment: @rakhi4110  thanks. - it is the answer to my question. please create answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agents on author(`/etc/replication/agents.author.html`) in the replication console(`/etc/replication.html`) gives the list of replication agents that are configured in the current instance.

You can configure the agents, test the connection, view replication logs, enable/disable the agent and check the status/clear/retry replication of the items in your replication queue and perform various other functions.

More info on Replication can be found [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/replication.html).